# A Seemingly Easy Indefinite Integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

So, I'm stuck with an integral. It asks- $$ \int e^x \sec(x) dx $$

I tried integration by parts, tried substituting. Nothing worked. Wolframalpha gave me some peculiar stuff(something called 'Hypergeometric function') which I don't understand at all.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If Wolfram Alpha gives a hypergeometric function, presumably there is no elementary antiderivative.  You can't integrate everything.

Comment: "seemingly" ??? The number of characters has no relation to the difficulty :-) Try $x^x$.

Comment: A hypergeometric $\phantom{}_2 F_1$ with complex parameters, hmm, such a joy! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, this is a non-elementary integral, but you can solve it in terms of Hypergeometric function, but it's quite messy.